# Magento 2 - repair table in database

Tags: magento2, database, table

I installed a new extension last night and in the morning my whole server crashed. I ran the SSH command mysqlcheck --all-databases -r and I noticed it said the table customer_grid_flat doesn't exist on one of my websites. How do I repair this?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I have the same :-(

Comment: I had to do a whole new installation to fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename your file `app/etc/env.php` so Magento 2 will show the installation screen again, no worries all data will keep saved, so run the install process again and run this commands below.

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento" 
mage cache:clean  
mage cache:flush 
mage indexer:reindex 
mage setup:upgrade 
mage deploy:mode:set developer 
mage setup:db-data:upgrade 
mage setup:db-schema:upgrade 
mage setup:db:status
```